# i have data "test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com" how to make the result look like this

Tags: php, codeigniter

**my code :**

```
  $read = $this->m_crud->read_data("subscribe","*");

   $newData=array();

      foreach($read as $key){
          $newData[] = $key["email"];
       }

    $to = implode(",",$newData);

    echo json_encode($to)
```

**result :**

```
"test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com"
```

**question** : how to make the results look like this:

```
"test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"
```

Comment: remove this `$to = implode(",",$newData);` and change this `echo json_encode($newData)`  ~ results `["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"]`  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/561ecaa6a66096cfc751d090a3c734284596df95)  And in JS it's an array not a string, so you have no parsing to do of it.  `data[0]` or `data[1]` etc.

Comment: In case you are not really asking for JSON, but actually want the result exactly as shown, the answer would be that you implode the array with the separator `", "`, and output an additional `"` before and after the whole thing …

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the implode() Function.The implode() is a builtin function in PHP and is used to join the elements of an array. The separator (,) parameter of implode() is recommended to always use two parameters for backwards compatibility.

```
<?php 
   $read = $this->m_crud->read_data("subscribe","*");

   $newData=array();

      foreach($read as $key){
          $newData[] = $key["email"];
       }
    echo json_encode($newData);
?>
```